# Why is it that denuding something means you strip it rather than dress it?

Tags: etymology, prefixes

When we *denude* something we strip it, like the branches of a tree. That seems a bit inverted to me, shouldn't it be to *nude*-something?

Comment: GR. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=denude http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=denudation

Comment: Like we *skin* a goat and *dress* a chicken.

Comment: And we *dust* the furniture.

Comment: Dust the top of the cake lightly with icing sugar.

Comment: @DavidWallace *Dusting* in this case is akin to *icing* -- not removing something off the cake, but applying sugar *dust*.

Answer (score 6):

Prefixes can have multiple uses. In the case of [denude](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/denude):

> Origin:
>
> late Middle English: from Latin denudare, **from de- 'completely'** + nudare 'to bare' (from nudus 'naked')

Comment: *de* ='completely' surprises me, though. Waiting to up vote.

Comment: In fact, that definition can decide the very validity of OP's question, and therefore if it should be closed.

Comment: @Kris some [definitions of de-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/de-) could mean *intensity*.

Answer (score 6):

Because sometimes Latin’s ***de-*** prefix meant something else than to strip something away or to undo or reverse the action of a verb. And so it also has come down to us as something else in English.

You were thinking of OED sense 6, so here are the OED’s senses 3–5 for ***de-*** to illustrate just a few of the other possibilities for that prefix:

> **3**. Down to the bottom, completely; hence thoroughly on and on, away; also methodically, formally:
>
> - as *dēclāmāre* to shout away, **declaim**;
> - *dēclārāre* to make quite clear, **declare**;
> - *dēnūdāre* to strip quite bare, **denude**;
> - *dēplōrāre* to weep as lost, **deplore**;
> - *dērelinquĕre* to abandon completely, **derelict**;
> - *dēspoliāre* to spoil utterly, **despoil**.
>
> **b.** To exhaustion, to the dregs:
>
> - as *dēcoquĕre* to boil down or away, **decoct**;
> - *dēliquēscĕre* to melt away, **deliquesce**.
>
> **4**. In a bad sense, so as to put down or subject to some indignity:
>
> - as *dēcipĕre* to take in, **deceive**;
> - *dēlūdĕre* to make game of, **delude**;
> - *dērīdēre* to laugh to scorn, **deride**;
> - *dētestārī* to abominate, **detest**.
>
> **5**. In late L., *dēcompositus* was used by the grammarians in the sense ‘formed or derived from a compound (word)’, passing later into that of ‘compounded over again, doubly or further compounded’; in this sense the word has in modern times been taken into chemistry, botany, etc. (see **decomposite**, **decompound**), and the prefix has been similarly used in other words, as **decomplex**, **demixture**.

There actually is a word that is constructed and means what you seem to be expecting of ***denude***, and that is ***debare***.  Again per the OED:

> *trans.* To strip down, make quite bare.
>
> Hence  † **deˈbared** *ppl. a.* So  † **deˈbare** *a.*, intensive of **bare** *a.*
>
> - 1567 Drant *Horace’s Arte of Poetrie* A ij, ― As wooddes are made debayre of leaues by turnyng of the yeare.
> - C. 1620 T. Robinson *M. Magd.* 223 ― Next her debared brests bewitch mine eyes.

As you see, it hasn’t been used much for quite some time.  The OED labels it obsolete.  Best stick with ***denude***.

Answer (score 0):

Though tchrist's answer is clearly correct, and the OED's sense 3 of *de-* governs the word *denude*, I was surprised to discover that Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary doesn't provide a useful answer to the OP's question.

In its entry for *denude*, the Eleventh Collegiate gives the etymology as

> ME, fr. L *denuduare*, fr. *de*- + *nudus* bare

But that dictionary's entry for *de*- is disappointingly incomplete:

> **de-** *prefix* [ME, fr. AF *de*-, *des-*, partly fr. L *de*- down, from, away (fr. *de*, prep.) and partly fr. L *dis*-; L *de* akin to OIr *di* from OE *tō* to—more at dis-] **1 a :** to do the opposite of [*deactivate*] **b :** reverse of [*de-emphasis*] **2 a :** remove (a specified thing) from [*delouse*] **b :** remove (from) a specified thing [*dethone*] **3 :** reduce [*devalue*] **4 :** something derived from (a specific thing) [*decompound*] : derived from something (of a specified nature) [*denominative*] **5 :** get off of (a specified thing) [*detrain*] **6 :** having a a molecule characterized by the removal of one or more atoms (of a specified element) [**deoxy*-]

The only definition here that is even remotely related to the OED's clear and succinct "down to the bottom, completely" definition of *de*- is the fourth one, which, besides being worded rather vaguely (in effect, "something derived from something else of a particular kind" as a noun and "being derived from something of a particular kind" as an adjective), doesn't offer an associated verb form with a definition along the lines of "derive from (something of a specified nature) [*denominate*]."

Merriam-Webster's treatment of *de*- appears to leave unexplained such common *de*- verbs in English as *default*, *delimit*, *denote*, *denude*, and *despoil*.

Answer (score -1):

No, it should not.

You are assuming that the verb *denude* has been constructed from the adjective *nude*.

That is not the case. The latin root is dēnūdō (and hence present infinitive dēnūdāre, perfect active dēnūdāvī, supine dēnūdātum.)

Comment: You could cite a reference to be helpful. In fact, it is *de* + *nude* alright, just that *nudere* itself here has the meaning "to strip," derived in turn from *nude*, bare. See links at comment under OP.